# How to Optimize this query (stuff part)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I Optimize this following query:

```
SELECT 

MONTH('1' + LEFT(Datename(month,visitDate),3) +'00') AS MONTH_NUMBER ,

VisitMonth = LEFT(Datename(month,visitDate),3)

,TotalVisits = Count(v.VisitID)

,TotalVisits_with_StandardReport = Count(CASE WHEN v.ReportStandard NOT IN (0,9) THEN   v.ReportStandard END)

,TotalVisits_with_FeedbackReport = Count(CASE WHEN v.DiscrepancyType IN (2,5) THEN v.DiscrepancyStatus END)

,Perc = 
CAST(100 - ISNULL(CAST((Count(CASE WHEN v.DiscrepancyType IN (2,5) THEN v.DiscrepancyType END) * 1.0 / Count(CASE WHEN v.ReportStandard NOT IN (0,9) THEN v.ReportStandard END)) * 100 AS FLOAT),0) AS NUMERIC(10,2))  


,VisitAssignmentID_with_FeedbackRpt = STUFF (( SELECT  ', ' + CAST(v2.AssignmentID  AS VARCHAR) from Visits v2
INNER JOIN 
Assignments a2 ON a2.AssignmentID = v2.AssignmentID
WHERE 
DATENAME(MONTH,v.VisitDate) = DATENAME(MONTH,v2.VisitDate) 
AND a2.ClientID IN (22,33) AND v2.DiscrepancyType IN (2,5)  
GROUP BY V2.AssignmentID 
FOR xml path('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM Visits v
INNER JOIN Assignments a ON a.AssignmentID = v.AssignmentID  
WHERE a.ClientID IN (22,33)
AND v.VisitDate BETWEEN '01/01/2013' AND '31/12/2013'

GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,v.VisitDate) 

ORDER BY MONTH_NUMBER
```

**Result**

[image]

**Second query which i tried to simplify and optimize (but query results are not same)**

I have tried to optimize the query and tried to simply the stuff inner query but i am not getting the results i want. It has reduced the total execution time though but results are not same.

```
  WITH ALL_CTE(MONTH_NUMBER,VisitMonth,VisitID,AssignmentID,ReportStandard,DiscrepancyStatus,DiscrepancyType,VisitA     ssignmentID_with_FeedbackRpt)
 AS
 -- Define the CTE query.

(
SELECT 
    MONTH('1' + LEFT(Datename(month,visitDate),3) +'00') AS MONTH_NUMBER ,
    VisitMonth = LEFT(Datename(month,visitDate),3)
   ,v.VisitID, v.AssignmentID ,  v.ReportStandard , v.DiscrepancyStatus, v.DiscrepancyType 

     ,VisitAssignmentID_with_FeedbackRpt = 
     STUFF (( SELECT  ', ' + CAST((CASE WHEN DiscrepancyType IN (2,5) THEN v.AssignmentID END)  AS VARCHAR)                 
            FOR xml path('')), 1, 2, '')

FROM Visits v
INNER JOIN Assignments a ON a.AssignmentID = v.AssignmentID
WHERE a.ClientID IN (22,33)
AND v.VisitDate BETWEEN '01/01/2013' AND '31/12/2013'
group by v.AssignmentID,visitDate,VisitID,ReportStandard,DiscrepancyStatus,DiscrepancyType

 )
-- Define the outer query referencing the CTE name.

SELECT 
MONTH_NUMBER
,VisitMonth  
,COUNT(VisitID) 
,TotalVisits_with_StandardReport = COUNT(CASE WHEN ReportStandard NOT IN (0,9) THEN  ReportStandard END)
,TotalVisits_with_FeedbackReport = COUNT(CASE WHEN DiscrepancyType IN (2,5) THEN DiscrepancyStatus END)

,isnull(VisitAssignmentID_with_FeedbackRpt,0)   
FROM ALL_CTE

GROUP BY MONTH_NUMBER,VisitMonth,VisitAssignmentID_with_FeedbackRpt
```

[image]

**Client Stats**

[image]

Comment: will you post your execution plan please

Comment: I have added the client stats, do you want me to add execution plan as well?

Comment: Yes please. The execution plan will tell us where the problem is, you can do it as a picture or as xml

Answer (score 0):

I think the only real optimization you can do here is make sure that you have an index on `AssignmentID` so that the inner join is quicker. All the other parts are pretty irrelevant, they are just conversions handled in memory.